# Close Tabs when clicked on active Button (No jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this Tabs Code-Snippet Editor:

```js
function openLanguage(evt, codeLanguage) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(codeLanguage).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.1s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%)
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

#result {
    height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

#tabs {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    #tabs {
        display: flex;
    }
    #result {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .tabcontent {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'HTML')">HTML</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'CSS')">CSS</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'JavaScript')">JavaScript</button>
</div>

<div id="tabs">
<div id="HTML" class="tabcontent">
  <p>Some HTML Code</p>
</div>

<div id="CSS" class="tabcontent">
  <p>Some CSS Code</p> 
</div>

<div id="JavaScript" class="tabcontent">
  <p>Some JS Code</p>
</div>

<div id="result">

</div>
```

If you click on one of these buttons, a tab will open next to the output.

I used this example from W3Schools and added a code part. It's still not perfect but you can see what it is.

How can I make it so that these tabs close when you have clicked on an active button?

(Completely without jQuery)

Comment: Just before improving this code, could you have this tabs group several times in the page? if yes, I would avoid using the `id` attribute as it has to be unique. Replace it with `class` attributes or `data-*` attributes so that you can have one single JS code that works for multiple instances of them in your page. Also avoid putting some `onclick` or other kind of JavaScript in the HTML itself. It's best to have HTML and JavaScript decoupled.

Comment: @PatrickJanser by improving i meant that i added a code part. But thanks

Comment: Yes, I understood that you did that, which is great! But as you are trying to improve it even more, you may consider changing a little bit the HTML structure. Typically you could link the tabs with the tabs content by grouping them in a parent div. This would help for the JavaScript logic if you have multiple instances of them in the page. Your `active` class on the tab could help you. When the user clicks on the tab, check if it's already active and if yes, remove the class and hide the tab content.

Comment: In pure/vanilla JS, I think most browsers support the `classList` property https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/classList. You can then use the `.contains()`, `.add()`, `.remove()`, `.toggle()` methods instead of manipulating the `className` property.

Comment: You may also consider a pure CSS solution such as this very neat one: https://codepen.io/renatorib/pen/rlpfj

Comment: @PatrickJanser he asked for a solution with his code. And instead of commenting so much, you could just add a answer with your solution

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 You are right. I appologize. I started the solution, the right way and then I saw that it was possible to do it without JavaScript so I stopped. Re-inventing the wheel isn't necessary. Chrwahl also gave a solution so I didn't find it very logical to spend more time on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I start out by finding the current tab (`currentTab`) using querySelector. After hiding all tabs and all content I test if the currentTab is different from the newly selected tab, if so I make is visible.

Btw. `querySelectoAll` and `forEach` makes it much easier to read the code.

```js
function openLanguage(evt, codeLanguage) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  let currentTab = document.querySelector('.tablinks.active');

  tabcontent = document.querySelectorAll("#tabs .tabcontent");
  tabcontent.forEach(content => content.style.display = "none");

  tablinks = document.querySelectorAll(".tab .tablinks");
  tablinks.forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove("active"));

  if (currentTab != evt.currentTarget) {
    document.getElementById(codeLanguage).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.1s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%)
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

#result {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

#tabs {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  #tabs {
    display: flex;
  }
  #result {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .tabcontent {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" data-lang="html" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'HTML')">HTML</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-lang="css" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'CSS')">CSS</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-lang="js" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'JavaScript')">JavaScript</button>
</div>

<div id="tabs">
  <div id="HTML" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Some HTML Code</p>
  </div>

  <div id="CSS" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Some CSS Code</p>
  </div>

  <div id="JavaScript" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Some JS Code</p>
  </div>

  <div id="result">
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey man! Thank you so much this is awesome!

Answer (score -2):

Much simpler solution. Added a `hidden` class.

Hope this works for you!

```js
function openLanguage(evt, codeLanguage) {
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        if (tabcontent[i].id != codeLanguage) tabcontent[i].classList.add("hidden");
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    document.getElementById(codeLanguage).classList.toggle("hidden");
    evt.currentTarget.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
}

.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.1s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
    filter: brightness(90%)
}

.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}

#result {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}

#tabs {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    #tabs {
        display: flex;
    }

    #result {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .tabcontent {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'HTML')">HTML</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'CSS')">CSS</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'JavaScript')">JavaScript</button>
</div>

<div id="tabs">
    <div id="HTML" class="tabcontent hidden">
        <p>Some HTML Code</p>
    </div>

    <div id="CSS" class="tabcontent hidden">
        <p>Some CSS Code</p>
    </div>

    <div id="JavaScript" class="tabcontent hidden">
        <p>Some JS Code</p>
    </div>

    <div id="result">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Click on HTML then css and then javascript